# Is there a formula to find this set of numbers?

Tags: python, math, numbers

I apologize for the title of this question, I honestly have no idea what this type of math is called. I will update it once I find out.

The puzzle will always have a list of numbers, length can be odd or even. In this case I have:

```py
puzzle = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The desired output is a list tuples, each tuple has a correct connection. EDIT: I've attached a screenshot of how I can tell what is a correct connection and what is not.[image: Example of correct connections]

```py
answer = [(0, 8), (1, 15), (2, 14), (3, 13), (4, 12), (5, 11), (6, 10), (7, 9), (1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (9, 15), (10, 14), (11, 13)]
```

I managed to write something that works for half of the connections which you can see here:

```py
from __future__ import division
puzzle = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
temp_connections = list()
x_connections = list()
middle_value = None
for dot in puzzle:
    source = puzzle.index(dot)
    destination = puzzle[-source]
    if source != 0 and source != destination and source not in temp_connections:
        # Connect the x adjacent dots.
        puzzle_connection = (source, destination)
        temp_connections.append(destination)
        x_connections.append(puzzle_connection)
    if source == 0:
        # Connect the most opposite at this angle.
        middle_value = int((len(puzzle)/2))
        x_connections.append((source, middle_value))

print(x_connections)
# [(0, 8), (1, 15), (2, 14), (3, 13), (4, 12), (5, 11), (6, 10), (7, 9)]
```

Unfortunately I am still missing the other 6 of the possible connections. Now I managed to get 3 of the missing 6 but I feel I am heading in the wrong direction.

```py
from __future__ import division

puzzle = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
temp_connections = list()
x_connections = list()
y_connections = list()
middle_value = None
for dot in puzzle:
    source = puzzle.index(dot)
    destination = puzzle[-source]
    if source != 0 and source != destination and source not in temp_connections:
        # Connect the x adjacent dots.
        puzzle_connection = (source, destination)
        temp_connections.append(destination)
        x_connections.append(puzzle_connection)

        # Connect the y adjacent dots.
        if source < middle_value and middle_value-source != source:
            # This gets the first 3
            y_connections.append((source, middle_value-source))
        elif source > middle_value:
            # This would get the last 3 but I don't think it's correct at all. Must be a better way...
            pass

    if source == 0:
        # Connect the most opposite at this angle.
        middle_value = int((len(puzzle)/2))
        x_connections.append((source, middle_value))

print x_connections
print y_connections
# [(0, 8), (1, 15), (2, 14), (3, 13), (4, 12), (5, 11), (6, 10), (7, 9)]
# [(1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1)]
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, even a hint at the type of math I need to be looking into would be awesome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do not see how you build the _"desired output is a list tuples"_ - you do not give any rules how to come to the _"correct connection"_ of tuples.

Comment: `int((len(puzzle)/2))` ==  `len(puzzle)//2`, `for dot in puzzle: source = puzzle.index(dot)` == `for source,dot in enumerate(puzzle)` (if you do not have duplicates in it) and other things that could be done better

Comment: Could you provide more explanation on how the puzzle works? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to help illustrate the connections I'm seeing. I hope that helps!

Comment: The "puzzle" list is a list of vertex around the side of an object with a single face. The list is always in order for the amount of vertex. The goal is to connect the vertexes to one another so the face is split up into quads like in the screenshot. If there's an odd number, there may be a triangle left over.

Comment: You seem to be putting the numbers in `puzzle` on the vertices of a regular `n-gon`, and your connections are some diagonals. Your rules for selecting the diagonals that you select are not spelled out. For example, why `(6,10)` rather than `(6,2)`? You also said that the length of `puzzle` can be either even or odd, but if it is odd there are no longer "opposite" vertices, so in that case the problem of how to select diagonals is even more unclear.

Comment: In the `answer` there is `(6, 10)` and `(2, 6)`. `(6, 2)` would also be acceptable as it's a two way connection, it just makes a single edge. Yes if it is odd, I thought I could just connect the last vertex to the previous one to make a triangle.

Comment: To add to my last comment, why `(6,10)` at all? Or `(2,14)`? Those are not edges in the screen shot. If you add such edges, then the face will no longer be partitioned into quadrilaterals (which you indicated that you want).

Comment: Yes sorry, they should be. Each vertex should have at least one connection to it. Floating vertex makes for bad geo for sure.

Comment: But if the goal *isn't* to partition the face into quadrilaterals, what is the goal? There are a very large number of ways that the list can be partitioned into pairs. You still haven't given any criterion that makes one partition preferable to another.

Comment: The goal is indeed to make quads. But on the chance there is an odd number, we cannot leave a floating vertex, so a triangle would be made by connecting to the last vertex that had previously connected.

Comment: It might help if you gave the output for different numbers of vertices. If I understand correctly, for `n = 6` you probably want `[(0,3), (1, 5), (2, 4)]` but it isn't clear what it would be for e.g. `n = 5`

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be 4 types of connections:

- horizontal connections between `i` and `N-i`
- vertical connections at "the left" between `i` and `N//2-i`
- vertical connections at "the right" mirroring the ones at "the left"
- an extra connection when there is an odd number of points

Here is a calculation and visualization of these answers for the 4 possible types of configuration:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(14, 9))
for N, ax in zip((4, 5, 6, 7, 16, 17, 18, 19), axes.ravel()):
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_title(f'N = {N}', size=16)
    ang = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
    x = np.sin(ang)
    y = np.cos(ang)
    for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        ax.text(xi * 1.1, yi * 1.1, i, ha='center', va='center')

    ans1 = [(i, N - i) for i in np.arange(1, N / 2)]
    ans2 = [(i, N // 2 - i) for i in np.arange(0, N / 4)]
    ans3 = [(N - i, N - (N // 2 - i)) for i in np.arange(1, N / 4)]
    ans4 = [(0, N - N // 2)] if N % 2 == 1 else []
    answer = np.array(ans1 + ans2 + ans3 + ans4, dtype=int)
    for ans in answer:
        ax.plot(x[ans], y[ans], 'b-', alpha=0.7)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Nice (+1). I think that you figured out what OP was trying to do, although I am not completely sure in the odd case (which wasn't really spelled out).

Comment: I first implemented the 16 case. Then ran and adapted it for 18 (there are 2 extra vertical lines). Then tried the same code with 17, where one line seemed to be obviously missing. Adding that line also worked for 19. It also went nice for small numbers, except for N=2. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?